# WatchKit sometimes not loading images

Tags: ios, watchkit

I have a number of images in my interface, some simply used as information feedback and others are there as part of Buttons.

The information feedback images are updated in the interface using code. The images which are part of buttons have the image choice defined in Xcode and they never change.

A number of users have sent me images showing screens where none of the buttons have images, ie they're blank. The buttons still work though.

The situation doesn't happen with all users and it works exactly as designed in the simulator.

All images are stored in the WatchKit app so have not been explicitly cached as that shouldn't be necessary. All images are in PNG format.

Has anyone else experienced this and is there a fix?

Comment: Are Watch Kit images called `UIImages`?

Comment: They're WKInterfaceImage objects. Dynamically changed ones are done using the setImageNamed method, this seems to always work. Images set using the inspector in XCode, for some users, don't display. All images are stored in bundles and are defined at all resolutions (1x, 2x & 3x)

Comment: Im having trouble that Images displayed by `setImageNamed` occasionally also don`t work.

Answer (score 1):

If the image files in your WatchKit app are "loose" (i.e. not in an assets catalog), make sure you have the "@2x" suffix in the file name. Many developers have reported issues where loose images display in the simulator but not on actual hardware.

I would highly recommend creating an assets catalog in your WatchKit app (not extension) that includes all of your Watch assets. Make sure that each image is set to "Device Specific" in the inspector panel and that "Apple Watch" is the only option selected. Using this technique, the actual file names don't matter.

[image]

I just happened to write a post with additional details that might be useful to you: http://blog.mikeswanson.com/post/118580394879/watchkit-image-tips

Comment: Totally agree that most folk miss this one. All my assets are stored in bundles already and marked as device specific. One difference is that they're stored in the 2x rather that model specific slots. Odd thing is that the other dynamically allocated images all work 100%.